# How do I send values to another view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a edit view whose textboxes needs to be assigned with some fields after i click an edit button against a record in a table in another view.

```
 <tbody>
                        @foreach (var client in this.Model.ClientsList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@client.Name</td>
                                <td>@client.PhoneNo</td>
                                <td>@client.Address</td>
                                <td>@client.ProjectNo</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="../Downloads/Clients/@client.Logo" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
```

This is the Edit view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Clients", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Clients</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Logo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Logo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Logo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectNo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I tried my best but couldn't do it. So asking here. I also tried putting it an object but that also didn't work. I know it can be shared via query strings but that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to edit the client data so You can pass data to another view by passing in TModelValue as third params like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", new { ID = client.Id })
```

Hope it will help. 
Regrads.

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can do this way

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", // <-- Link text  
                 "url/GetClientDataById/2" // <-- Action Method Name  
                 )
```

Preferred Way

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "url/GetClientDataById",  new { Id = client.Id })


        public string GetClientDataById(int Id)
        {
        //perform your DB logic here and then return your object to view
        }
```